# select query not working according to the session array

Tags: php, database, arrays, session, select

i have two problems and i need to solve it on urgent based

1) select query with session array and problem is that when i used `implode` or `join` On `$pid = join(',',$_SESSION['pid']);`  then it is showing only `array array array` when i used `var_dump` it is showing values which are in `session pid`?

2) How do i select multiple mywishlist ids via two different `PIDS` and that function will use on Page3?

3) when i used `($pid)` in select query it is showing error

**Id Problem

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1**

**Page1 Where Session Pid Creating**

```
$_SESSION['pid']=array();   
$_SESSION['pid'][]= implode (",",$_POST['pid']);
```

**Page2 Where I Want To Use Select Query**

```
$pid = join(',',$_SESSION['pid']); 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN (pid)")
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    <input type="text" name="wid[]" value="<?php echo $row['wid']//[$j]; ?>" />
<?php  }?>
```

**Page3 Where I Want To Use Wid**

```
$max=count($_REQUEST['wid']);
for($a=0; $a<$max; $a++){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE mywishlist SET     
        cusername='".$_SESSION['username']."',uid='".$_SESSION['id']."', 
        email='".$email."'  where id='".$_REQUEST['wid'][$a]."'") 
    or die ("Cart Email Query");
}
```

**Databse Image**

[image]

**Page2 Live Image**

[image]

Comment: You might want to edit the title to something more specific to get the right people here.

Comment: You may want to also use $pid not just pid in your IN() bit

Answer (score 0):

Set it like this. key pid in session will be an array

```
$_SESSION['pid']= implode (",",$_POST['pid']);
```

tretrieve and assign it like this

```
$pid = $_SESSION['pid'];
```

Now use it like this

```
$query  =   "SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN ($pid)";
$rec    =   mysqli_query($query);
```

Comment: double implode? that would end up as an invalid string for the in()

Comment: when i used ($pid) in select query it is showing error

`Id Problem You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1`